# How to compress multiple files with similar names?

Tags: batch, script, zip, archiving, 7-zip

So I've got some 20 000 files that I want to compress and group by following logic:

- compress every file that have identical characters up to `(`
- also include files that have no `(`

So the files are like

```
file_123.foo
file_123(abc).foo
file_123(b9)(ca)[a1].foo

foobar(a).foo
foobar.foo
foobar(123).foo
```

which should be compressed to

```
file_123.7z
foobar.7z
```

I'm open to windows batch files, unix scripts or any compression program (I can work from there), though the most convenient combo would be .7z and windows.

**UPDATE**

cYrus gave me a perfect answer, the problem was my question wasn't precise enough :) Now that I'm smarter, here's the next set of problems I haven't figured out how to get around yet:

So everything works perfectly unless this happens:

```
file_123(abc).foo
file_123456789(b9).foo
```

Those two shouldn't be grouped, i.e., they should end up in two separate files:

```
file_123.7z
file_123456789.7z
```

This one:

```
for pfx in $(for i in *.foo; do echo "${i%%[.(]*}"; done | sort -u); do 7z a "$pfx.7z" $pfx*; done
```

creates those two separately, **but** the shorter file works as catch-all, i.e., `file_123.7z` includes both files, which it shouldn't.

Comment: Are all the files even in the same directory?

Comment: Yes, yes they are. Oh and the files have spaces in them, which seems to break something in the solution @cYrus provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Linux

This should work:

```
for pfx in $(for i in *.foo; do echo "${i%%[.(]*}"; done | sort -u); do 7z a "$pfx.7z" $pfx[.\(]*; done
```

### Explanation

First we have to iterate all over the input files (`*.foo`) and strip away the suffix (`${i%%[.(]*}`) obtaining:

```
file_123
file_123
file_123
foobar
foobar
foobar
```

Then we can remove duplicates with `sort -u`:

```
file_123
foobar
```

Finally for each prefix (`$pfx`) we can build the archive using the prefix itself as both the name of the archive (`"$pfx.7z"`) and the pattern to identify the files (`$pfx[.\(]*`); obtaining the equivalent of:

```
7z a file_123.7z 'file_123(abc).foo' 'file_123(b9)(ca)[a1].foo' 'file_123.foo'
7z a foobar.7z 'foobar(123).foo' 'foobar(a).foo' 'foobar.foo'
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.

Comment: Fair enough, updated!

Comment: @cYrus Thanks for trying - I'm sure we're close! Something goes wrong however;
As an example, I end up with a 2.7z, which has all sorts of files starting with the character 2 - 
20-21-22.foo, 2088.foo etc.
Also, it has additional .7z's in it, like 2.7z, 20.7z, 20000.7z - all of which are ... hmm got me thinking. They seem to break at the first whitespace.

Comment: And there you have it! THANK YOU! Your solution does break if the filenames have whitespaces in them and as I didn't know how to fix that, I simply replaced spaces with underscores, after which it worked perfectly.

Comment: Oh yes... since you used the underscore in your example I assumed no whitespaces. You're welcome!

Comment: And on that note: found another problem now that I started to look into the files - nothing wrong with your answer, I just wasn't able to ask precise enough question :) New updated question above.

Comment: @Viritys I have edited my answer to reflect your update, note how `$pfx*` is now `$pfx[.\(]*` to force the first character after the prefix to be `.` or `(`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, instead of just giving you a shell script, I'm going to show you 7zips context menu.

**Step 1**: Open your folder with all these files in.

**Step 2**: Click on "Name" to order all files by their name (This will make it easy to select files with similar name beginnings).

**Step 3**: With the **right** mouse button, drag and drop the select box over all the files you want to compress in a single file ( So, foobar(a).foo, foobar.foo ,foobar(123).foo )

**Step 4**: When you let go of the right mouse button, the context menu will appear. Go to   7Zip  >  Add to PARENT_DIRECTORY.7z

Where PARENT_DIRECTORY is the name of the folder these files are in.
So if the folder you are in is called, 'files' it will add them to 'files.7z'

**Step 5**: Rename this new compressed file by right clicking the new 7Zip file and clicking 'Rename'.

Comment: Thanks - this would work, if I had less than approx 8000 groupings to do - as it is, I would grow quite a bit older before I would have it done :)